# Undefined index: file, even when the form is submitted

Tags: php, html

I know that this error means you're trying to access an array element that doesn't exist.
But still, I'm having a problem with this PHP code, the form is submitting as I can see..

well to get sure I also tried the POST values and they were all submitted and available..

THE WHOLE ERROR CODE: Undefined index: file in 'filename' on line ' '
and Undefined index: file in 'filename' on line ' ' (well those lines means the 17 and 18 on the php code here)

The PHP CODE

```
<?php

                        if (isset($_POST['Submit_insert'])) //Inserting
                        {



                            $pid = $_SESSION['provider_ID'];                            
                            $branch=$_GET['branch'];//as a number
                            $branch_name=$_GET['branch_name']; // as a string 
                            $prid=$_POST['PRID'];
                            $name=$_POST['NAME'];
                            $manu=$_POST['MANU'];
                            $size=$_POST['SIZE'];
                            $price=$_POST['PRICE'];
                            $cat=$_POST['CAT'];
                            $newname="$pid$branch$prid.jpg";
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"./images_store/" . $newname);
                            echo "Stored in: " . "./images_store/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];


                        }
    ?>
```

The HTML markup?

```
                <form id='register' action='./controlPage.php?branch=".$branch_no."&branch_name=".$branch." ' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
                <center>
                <table border='0'>
                <legend>Inserting a Record in the " . $branch /*From the form*/ . " of " . $_SESSION['provider_name'] . "</legend>
                    <br>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product ID :
                        <td height='39'><input type='text' name='PRID' />
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product Name :
                        <td height='39'><input type='text' name='NAME' />
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product Manufacturer :
                        <td height='39'><input type='text' name='MANU' />
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product Size/Weight :
                        <td height='39'><input type='text' name='SIZE' />
                        <tr>
                        <td>Product Price :
                        <td height='39'><input type='text' name='PRICE' />
                        <tr>
                        <td>Image File :
                        <td><input type='file' name='file' id='file'>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Product Category :
                        <td height='39'><select name='CAT'>
                                        <option value='GOODS'>GOODS</option>
                                        <option value='FROZEN GOODS'>FROZEN GOODS</option>                                                
                                        <option value='DAIRY'>DAIRY</option>
                                        <option value='DELI MEAL'>DELI MEAL</option>
                                        <option value='BAKERY/PASTRY'>BAKERY/PASTRY</option>
                                        <option value='DRINKS'>DRINKS</option>
                                        <option value='CANDIES/COOKIES'>CANDIES/COOKIES</option>
                                        <option value='HEALTH/HYGINE'>HEALTH/HYGINE</option> 
                                        <option value='GIFTS'>GIFTS</option>                                               
                                        </select>
                    <tr>
                        <td >  
                        <td height='34'></br>                            
                     <input type='submit' name='Submit_insert' value='Create a Record' />
                </table>
                </fieldset>
                <table border='0'>
                     <tr>

                     </tr>
                </table>
                </center>
                </form>
```

Comment: What about posting the full error displayed?

Comment: in which line you got undefined index?

Comment: Why are you using $_GET for `brunch` and `brunch_name`?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` i guess here is the error

Comment: did you start_session() in your page?

Comment: Well its the file.. as I wrote in the question.. Anyways gonna show that on the code.

Comment: @Fabio look at his code... Those ARE `$_GET` vars..

Comment: Yea there's a start_session();

Comment: @joran-den-houting: you are right

Comment: @Umar: add full error in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the enctype in the form:

```
<form id='register' enctype="multipart/form-data" action='./controlPage.php?branch=".$branch_no."&branch_name=".$branch." ' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

Comment: Yeah.. Here it goes :\